# How does XMLSocketReceiver and SocketReceiver work?

Tags: java, log4j

I'm studying XMLSocketReceiver(bec. I want to run Chainsaw) ,which leads me to  SocketReceiver.

In the [SocketReceiver javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/receivers/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketReceiver.html) I read

> SocketReceiver receives a remote logging event on a configured socket
>   and "posts" it to a LoggerRepository as if the event was generated
>   locally. This class is designed to receive events from the
>   SocketAppender class (or classes that send compatible events).
>
> Once the event has been "posted", it will be handled by the appenders
>   currently configured in the LoggerRespository.

How does that work,  to `"posts" it to a LoggerRepository` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think about this is that Chainsaw can really only process 'local' logging events - and the way it does that is by using its own custom appender that is registered programmatically.

Much like a FileAppender sends 'local' logging events to a file, Chainsaw's custom appender sends local logging events to tabs in the UI.

Where the Receivers come in is that there needs to be a way to get these 'not-local' logging events (from a log file in the case of VFSLogFilePatternReceiver, from the network in the case of SocketReceiver) to become 'local' logging events that can be processed by Chainsaw' appender.

Once the logging events are 'received' by the Receiver, the receiver 'appends' them, very similar to how you do when you call log.info("my log message").  These (now) local logging events are received by appenders (including Chainsaw's appender).

One experiment you can try to see this: add a FileAppender definition to a Chainsaw config file.  The events received by Receivers will also be sent to the FileAppender.

By the way, I'd suggest trying the latest developer snapshot of Chainsaw: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy - tons of new features.

I hope that helps,

Scott